# Perl - X64bits system and X32bits system

Tags: perl

I would like to ask why is my script cant work in window X64bits system. This script are working in X32bits before. But i dont why it was having error as "can not open input file"

And there is no Output generate in X64bits system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $directory = 'D:/Script_Code/Perl/Test/Datalog/Unit_80';

my $testna = 'FW OTP Check UVLO VIN Voltage';
my $testpin = 'vrect';
my $testnb = 'FW OTP Checksum Readback';
my $testnc = 'FW OTP Checksum Difference';
my $testnd = 'FW Checksum Pat Pin Fail Count';

my @header = ( 'Unit#', 'Test_Name', 'Pin_Name', 'Measure_Data', 'Upper_limit' );
my $format = "%-8s %-40s %-15s %-15s %-1s\n";
my $outfile = "$directory.sdc";

open (OUT, ">$outfile" );
open (INF, "$directory") || die (" can not open input file \n" );

printf $format, @header;
printf OUT $format, @header;

while ( <INF> ) {

if ( /Device#:\s*(\d+)/ )
{   $unit = $1;
    next;    }

chomp;

my @fields = split /\s{2,}/;

if ( $fields[2] eq $testna and $fields[3] eq $testpin ) {             # TEMP_SENSE_VBE
    printf $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5];
    printf OUT $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5];
}
if ( $fields[2] eq $testnb ) {             # TEMP_SENSE_VBE
    printf $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5];
    printf OUT $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5];
}
if ( $fields[2] eq $testnc ) {             # TEMP_SENSE_VBE
    printf $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5], $fields[6];
    printf OUT $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5], $fields[6];
}
if ( $fields[2] eq $testnd ) {             # TEMP_SENSE_VBE
    printf $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5], $fields[6];
    printf OUT $format, $unit, $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[5], $fields[6];
}

}
      close (INF) || die "cannot close input file !!";
      close (OUT);
```

Comment: If you have two questions, ask them separately. It's not possible to tick two correct answers to one question at the same time.

Comment: I don't see any reason this would not work an a 64bit platform. Are you getting any error messages? Please [edit] your question and indent your code properly, it's very hard to read.

Comment: @choroba i have make it into one question.

Comment: @simbabque the whole code was like that. How to do my code properly?

Comment: It's just not easy to read it the way you have the code. I'm sure it would be easier to read if it was indented a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a related to the architecture of the Perl build, the OS build, or the system.

Start by checking what error you got!

```
open (OUT, ">", $outfile)
   or die("Can't create \"$outfile\": $!\n");
open (INF, "<", $directory)
   or die("Can't open \"$directory\": $!\n");
```

Comment: With the code . i have the error as " Can't open ..... No such file or directorv "